# react-router transitionTo(routeNameOrPath, [params[, query]]) hide query from URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am firing a method :
`this.transitionTo('route', {},{search: this.state.search, type: this.state.type});`

which passes query params in URL `http://...route?search=%param10&type=param2`

Is there equivalent method that passes these parameters without printing in URL ??

Comment: Better to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891667/react-js-pass-parameters-with-router-not-in-url

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
this.transitionTo("route", { search: this.state.search, type: this.state.type });
```