# Getting ReactTransitionGroup and Redux-Simple-Router to work together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux, react-router-redux

My coworker and I are trying to wrap `redux-simple-router` navigation (which we've had working for a while) in a `ReactTransitionGroup` element so that its lifecycle methods can be called on a route change. We've tried a whole bunch of versions, but haven't figured out a way to get it working.

Our current iteration creates a wrapper right under the `ReactTransitionGroup` (which is a child of `Provider`) so that lifecycle methods can be defined at a place where both the route state and children are accessible. This wrapper's render and `componentWillAppear` methods are definitely called on initial app load (in the browser), but not when navigating (using Redux Simple Router) between pages in the app. That code, more or less, is on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sashafklein/ef4d9742279010ca7f8f).

Most notably, we tried the `cloneElement` method from React with a regenerated key (e.g., through `history.createKey()`) each time, but couldn't get the lifecycle methods to fire on any route changes.

What's the idiomatic way to wrap simple-router components in a `ReactTransitionGroup` with `redux-simple-router`?

**UPDATES**

I've tried a new version, in which I wrap each individual route with its own `TransitionWrapper` class, as in [this second gist](https://gist.github.com/sashafklein/23295ee886ef79232857) (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component/)).

When that `TransitionWrapper` extends `React.Component` (as in the example), the `render` method is called, but nothing else. The site works fine (but I can't access the transition hooks).

When it extends `ReactTransitionGroup`, I hit an error on line 99 of the `performAppear` method on the `ReactTransitionGroup` object, a snippet of which is below:

```
performAppear: function (key) {
  this.currentlyTransitioningKeys[key] = true;

  var component = this.refs[key];

  if (component.componentWillAppear) { /* error here */
    component.componentWillAppear(this._handleDoneAppearing.bind(this, key));
  } else {
    this._handleDoneAppearing(key);
  }
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentWillAppear' of undefined

That's getting raised, because `this.refs` is an empty object. (`key` is correct).

Notably, if I close Chrome debugger so that the error is skipped, the site still works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution was to create a function that returned *another* function that in turn returned the component wrapped in a `ReactTransitionGroup`.

```
var transitionWrap = (component, myKey) => {
  return () => {
    return ( 
      <ReactTransitionGroup>
        { React.createElement(component, { key: myKey } ) }
      </ReactTransitionGroup>
    )
  }
}

const routeConfig = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: AppContainer,
    childRoutes: [
      { path: "/signed-out",
        component: LoggedOut,
        childRoutes: [
          { path: "/home", component: transitionWrap(Home, browserHistory.createKey())                            }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routeConfig} />
    </Provider>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Works perfectly (giving the component access to Transition Group methods), with one exception -- the child component (ie `Home`) **cannot** be `connect`ed to Redux global state. If it needs to be, that component can essentially just be a wrapper that renders *another* component that connects to Redux state, so that `Home` (for example) is really just there to handle animations, and its child component takes care of everything data-related.