# React load json data based on route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my following routes.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './index.jsx';
import Test1 from './test1.jsx';
import Test2 from './test2.jsx';
import TestWrapper from './wrapper.jsx';

import url from './url.json';

var routes = url.url.map(function(el){
   return (<Route key={el} path={el} component={Test1} />);
});

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
        {routes}
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

I am going to have a list of projects that will be using always the same component hence:

```
var routes = url.url.map(function(el){
   return (<Route key={el} path={el} component={Test1} />);
});
```

and a test1.jsx as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import data from './data.json';

class Test1 extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        // if is route "title1" load title1
        // if is route "title2" load title2
        // if is route "title3" load title3
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test1;
```

my url.json is:

```
{
  "url": [
    "title1",
    "title2",
    "title3",
    "title4",
    "title5"
  ]
}
```

I am fairly new to react, how can I pass to "test1" content based on the url? 
Ideally I will have a separate json file for the content..
Ex. if I am on localhost:8080/title1 I would like content loaded only for title1.

Comment: Why dont you create 5 components that load title1, title2 and so on. And call them on url accordingly using router. You are kind of trying to implement your own router it seems.

Comment: I think it's very repetitive to have 5 components that are identical and only different in data... I was hoping there could be a dynamic way of achieving the same result, using a loop perhaps...

Comment: If they are different in data only. You can pass data via props from router itself. So You will have one component that takes some props and renders according to props.

Comment: You could use the injected location from the router to get the pathname and load the data based on the pathname passed to the component.  [https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#injected-props](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#injected-props)

Comment: But wouldn't that be a bad practice ? Because urls and component will be coupled

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component
and comment by ciantic- "you could add a stateless component syntax (just lambda) there also, it's pretty short <Route path="comments" component={() => (<Comments myProp="value" />)}/>"