# ReactJS navigating to using router?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I pass the information displayed by that particular `<div/>` so that I can display that particular information in the route that I navigated to as well?

Thank you and will accept/upvote the answer

Comment: Do any of these methods work for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component

Comment: @Jayce444 sorry but what am I supposed to look for?

Comment: Have a look at Thomas E's and ColCh's answers in that thread and if you could use those methods for passing the props on

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand your exact problem, but I assume you just want to pass params to the route you navigate to using `<Link>`

Take a look at this: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link

In the documentation, about `to` prop it says:

> A location descriptor. Usually this is a string or an object [...]
>
> If it's an object it can have four keys:
>
> - `pathname`: A string representing the path to link to.
> - `query`: An object of key:value pairs to be stringified. [...]

And the example of this:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/hello', query: { name: 'ryan' } }}>
  Hello
</Link>
```

So your case might look like:

```
render() {
  var profile = this.props.profile;
  var query = {
    firstName: profile.firstName,
    lastName: profile.lastName
  };

  return (
    <Link to={{ pathname: '/details', query: query }}>
      <div>
        <div>
          {profile.firstName}
        </div>
        <div>
          {profile.lastName}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

Your details page should then be able to access the params from: `this.props.routeParams` object which will have your query params that you passed in

Comment: I gave it an attempt as exactly but with `query: profile`, but I only see `__proto__: Object` for both `routeParams` and `params`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have not tested this code I wrote, I will do that if I don't forget tonight. :)
Try searching in `this.props.location.query`, I have mistaken query with route params.

Comment: If you want to access data from route params instead of query params, you must define your route like this: 

`<Route component={Details} path='/details/:firstName/:lastName' />`

And use link like this:

`<Link path={{'/details/' + profile.firstName + '/' + profile.lastName}}>`

Then it should be available on: `this.props.routeParams`
Again, haven't tested, but if it works, I'll modify my original answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this :

Your router :

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route component={Root} path='/'>
    <IndexRoute component={Profile}/>
    <Route component={Details} path='details/:id'/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Then you can create your link like

`<Link to="details/profile">Profile</Link>`

And then inside details you can check for passed id with

`this.props.params.id`

and then depending on that id you can show your data.