# How do I pass state through React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

Here is the file that's causing me trouble:

```
var Routers = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return{
      userName: "",
      relatives: []
    }
  },

  userLoggedIn: function(userName, relatives){
    this.setState({
      userName: userName,
      relatives: relatives,
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" userLoggedIn={this.userLoggedIn} component={LogIn}/>
        <Route path="feed" relatives={this.state.relatives} userName={this.state.userName} component={Feed}/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
});
```

I am trying to pass the new `this.state.relatives` and `this.state.userName` through the routes into my "feed"-component. But I'm getting this error message:

> Warning: [react-router] You cannot change ; it will be
> ignored

I know why this happens, but  don't know how else I'm supposed to pass the states to my "feed"-component.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29720488/444829 The `<Route>` there is from an old version,so you would continue to use the `component` prop, not the `handler` one that that answer uses.

Comment: Will write up an answer with an explanation.

Comment: nononono dont! i already found a solution! i deleted the comment i made immediately after i found the solution, but unfortunately u seem to have red it already. thanks a lot though :)

Comment: @PaulS on second thought i'm always trying to learn and the solution i found appears to be only a semi-solution. do you mind explaining me how your mentioned solution would look like in my scenario? would be really great! :)

Comment: Feel free to leave your updated solution as an answer and then mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 51):

**tl;dr** your best bet is to use a store like `redux` or `mobx` when managing state that needs to be accessible throughout your application. Those libraries allow your components to connect to/observe the state and be kept up to date of any state changes.

#### What is a `<Route>`?

The reason that you cannot pass props through `<Route>` components is that they are not real components in the sense that they do not render anything. Instead, they are used to build a route configuration object.

That means that this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <Route path='foo' component={Foo} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

is equivalent to this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory} routes={{
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'foo',
      component: Foo
    }
  ]
}} />
```

The routes are only evaluated on the initial mount, which is why you cannot pass new props to them.

#### Static Props

If you have some static props that you want to pass to your store, you can create your own higher order component that will inject them into the store. Unfortunately, this only works for static props because, as stated above, the `<Route>`s are only evaluated once.

```
function withProps(Component, props) {
  return function(matchProps) {
    return <Component {...props} {...matchProps} />
  }
}

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={App}>
          <Route path='foo' component={withProps(Foo, { test: 'ing' })} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

#### Using `location.state`

`location.state` is a convenient way to pass state between components when you are navigating. It has one major downside, however, which is that the state only exists when navigating within your application. If a user follows a link to your website, there will be no state attached to the location.

#### Using A Store

So how do you pass data to your route's `component`s? A common way is to use a store like `redux` or `mobx`. With `redux`, you can `connect` your component to the store using a higher order component. Then, when your route's `component` (which is really the HOC with your route component as its child) renders, it can grab up to date information from the store.

```
const Foo = (props) => (
  <div>{props.username}</div>
)

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    value: state.username
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Foo)
```

I am not particularly familiar with `mobx`, but from my understanding it can be even easier to setup. Using `redux`, `mobx`, or one of the other state management is a great way to pass state throughout your application.

> **Note:** You can stop reading here. Below are plausible examples for passing state, but you should probably just use a store library.

#### Without A Store

What if you don't want to use a store? Are you out of luck? No, but you have to use an **experimental feature** of React: the [`context`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). In order to use the `context`, one of your parent components has to explicitly define a `getChildContext` method as well as a `childContextTypes` object. Any child component that wants to access these values through the `context` would then need to define a `contextTypes` object (similar to `propTypes`).

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      username: this.state.username
    }
  }

}

MyApp.childContextTypes = {
  username: React.PropTypes.object
}

const Foo = (props, context) => (
  <div>{context.username}</div>
)

Foo.contextTypes = {
  username: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

You could even write your own higher order component that automatically injects the `context` values as props of your `<Route>` `component`s. This would be something of a "poor man's store". You could get it to work, but most likely less efficiently and with more bugs than using one of the aforementioned store libraries.

#### What about `React.cloneElement`?

There is another way to provide props to a `<Route>`'s `component`, but it only works one level at a time. Essentially, when React Router is rendering components based on the current route, it creates an element for the most deeply nested matched `<Route>` first. It then passes that element as the `children` prop when creating an element for the next most deeply nested `<Route>`. That means that in the `render` method of the second component, you can use `React.cloneElement` to clone the existing `children` element and add additional props to it.

```
const Bar = (props) => (
  <div>These are my props: {JSON.stringify(props)}</div>
)

const Foo = (props) => (
  <div>
    This is my child: {
      props.children && React.cloneElement(props.children, { username: props.username })
    }
  </div>
)
```

This is of course tedious, especially if you were to need to pass this information through multiple levels of `<Route>` `component`s. You would also need to manage your state within your base `<Route>` component (i.e. `<Route path='/' component={Base}>`) because you wouldn't have a way to inject the state from parent components of the `<Router>`.

Comment: the question was changing the state of route itself

Comment: Please note that `React.PropTypes` has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the "prop-types" library instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Comment: So why is there a .state property in the LocationDescriptorObject interface? This is confusing - I cannot find anything in the docs... I mean I am using redux anyways but what is the intention of it?

Comment: @YannicHamann location.state comes from the browser (the first argument to history.pushState/replaceState is serializable state to associate with location) and comes with caveats like it being null when you navigate directly to a page. I find that location.state is best for temporary data, like a URL to navigate to after logging in and "real" state is better to keep elsewhere.

Comment: This is pretty outdated in 2022. It's also opinionated and misleading. Using a global store alone has the same issues as passing the state via navigation, and the author made no indication of the state needing to be "accessible throughout the application". They just need to pass the state when they navigate, which is not something that warrants a global store.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a late answer, but you can do it this way:

```js
  export default class Routes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { config: 'http://localhost' };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
                        <Route path="/lectures" exact 
                          render={() => <Lectures config={this.state.config} />} />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This way, you can reach config props inside the `Lecture` component.

This is a little walk around the issue but it is a nice start.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up that if you're using a `query string` you need to add `search`.

For example:

```
{
  key: 'ac3df4', // not with HashHistory!
  pathname: '/somewhere',
  search: '?some=search-string',
  hash: '#howdy',
  state: {
    [userDefined]: true
  }
}
```

It took like 20 minutes to figure out why my route was not being rendered

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the state of the React-router once the router component is mounted. You can write your own HTML5 route component and listen for the url changes.

```
class MyRouter extend React.component {
   constructor(props,context){
   super(props,context);
   this._registerHashEvent = this._registerHashEvent.bind(this)

 } 

 _registerHashEvent() {
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", this._hashHandler.bind(this), false);
  }
  ...
  ...

render(){
  return ( <div> <RouteComponent /> </div>)
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is really answering the original question.  How does this provide the ability to tie a route to state?

Answer (score 0):

For those like me,

You can also normally render this:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router, 
  Router, 
  Link, 
  Switch 
} from 'react-router-dom'

<Router>
  <Switch>
   <Link to='profile'>Profile</Link>

   <Route path='profile'>
     <Profile data={this.state.username} />
   </Route>
   <Route component={PageNotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

This worked for me!