# Unable to access this.props.location in component after redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Somewhere in component 1, I have this:

```
if (redirectToReferrer) {
    return <Redirect to={{
          pathname: "/test/new",
          state: { event: "test" }
     }} />;
}
```

In my component 2, I have this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.location) //undefined
}
```

According to the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect), this should work.

> The state object can be accessed via this.props.location.state in the
>   redirected-to component. This new referrer key (which is not a special
>   name) would then be accessed via this.props.location.state.referrer in
>   the Login component pointed to by the pathname '/login'

Why is `this.props.location` undefined?

Comment: did you want to pass state to the other component or you just need to location (path) ?

Comment: @AmirmohammadMoradi I want to be able to access the state in my second component, like it's mentioned in the docs via: `this.props.location.state.event`

Comment: did you test { browserHistory } ?

Comment: based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466055/how-do-i-pass-state-through-react-router your code should work. can u upload your code on fiddle or sandbox to see?

Comment: @AmirmohammadMoradi do I need to include browserHistory in the <Router>? I see it mentioned from time to time, or is it automaticlaly handled?

Comment: to use browserHistory you should do : `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'` at first.

Comment: @AmirmohammadMoradi apparently it was deprecated, and replcaed by BrowserRouter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170998/discussion-between-amirmohammad-moradi-and-rottenoats).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Same problem here.

Answer (score 6):

Ensure "/test/new" is defined by a `<Route/>` component in **App.js** or wherever you have defined the routes.

```
<Route path="/test/new" component={NewTestComp}/>
```

If you've defined the  using the render method make sure you are passing the props to your component like this.

```
<Route path="/test/new" render={(props) => <NewTestComp {...props}/>}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically components directly routed like this:

```
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
```

has props provided by react router such as location so make sure wherever you are redirecting, that component has a route defined.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of react-router-dom. Currently on version 5.2.0