# How to add State in React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When pressing the icon i want my application to navigate me to localhost:8080/editrevision+700 (700 being the id of that specific item)

```
<Menu.Item className="edit" 
   as={Link} 
   to="/editrevision" + {revisionItem.id}> 
   <i className="far fa-edit"/> 
</Menu.Item>
```

i keep getting syntax error on this, all suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466055/how-do-i-pass-state-through-react-router check this, it is helpfull for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the syntax of the `to`. You should wrap the whole value in curly braces.

The best way to pass id a parameter is as `/editrevision/700`. And, when you set the route, set its path as `/editrevision/:id`. The id can be retrieved through `this.props.match.params.id`.

```
<Menu.Item className="edit" 
   as={Link} 
   to={"/editrevision" + revisionItem.id}
   > 
       <i className="far fa-edit"/> 
</Menu.Item>
```

Comment: and that solved my whole issue.
Thank you very much for taking your time and solving this.

Comment: @ArastoSahbaei, you're welcome! Added a little tip to help you up. As this solves your problem, feel free to mark it as solution.