# In ReactJs using routes, how do I pass a hidden parameter without being in the URL?

Tags: reactjs

Currently in my code I need to pass a value from one component to the other through a button using router link ..
I am able to do this, but this value is appearing in the URL, appearing as if I had sent a GET.
I want to be able to pass this value on to the other component in a hidden way.

See the important parts of my code:

In TotalCartComponent:

```
<Link to={"/orderproduct/" + total}>ADVANCE</Link>
```

In OrderProduct:

```
   <h1>HELLO!!</h1>
   <h4>Total is: {this.props.match.params.total}</h4>
```

In AppShell:

```
 <main>
     <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Main}/>
            <Route path="/mycart" component={MyCart}/>            
            <Route path="/orderproduct/:total"  component={OrderProduct}/>
            <Route path="/view1" component={View1}/>
     </Switch>
 </main>
```

Comment: What about if you pass the param in base64 format?

Comment: I'd recommend `location.state`

Comment: I saw that it had this state, but I couldn't pass it and redeem it on OrderProduct
Do you have any functional example using this router link and passing the parameter with the state?

Comment: Hi, I managed to pass a hidden parameter through the state!
I just had to change the link

In this way:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466055/how-do-i-pass-state-through-react-router

Thanks to all for your help!