# Passing props inside Link React Typescript Route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I need to pass props inside the Link react Router to another component, but I can't due to the interface or type declarations that I don't understand. I've being searching around and I can't find anything to this problem (Typescript).

Here is the code of my component:

```js
const ImageGallery = () => {

   interface passProps {
      backUrl?: string
   }

   const backUrl = '/some/other/value';

   return (
      <Gallery>
         {images.map((x, i) => (
         <Link key={x} to={{ pathname: 'page', query: { backUrl } }}>
         ...
```

and here is the error:

```
(property) backUrl: string
Type '{ pathname: string; query: { backUrl: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'LocationDescriptor<unknown> | ((location: Location<unknown>) => LocationDescriptor<unknown>)'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'query' does not exist in type 'LocationDescriptorObject<unknown> | ((location: Location<unknown>) => LocationDescriptor<unknown>)'.ts(2322
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add state to `<Link>` components via a `state` property.

[Previously answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466055/how-do-i-pass-state-through-react-router)