# Changing the URL in react-router v4 without using Redirect or Link

Tags: javascript, react-router, material-ui, react-router-v4

I'm using [react-router v4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) and [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/) in my React app. I was wondering how to change the URL once there is a click on a `GridTile` within [GridList](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/grid-list).

My initial idea was to use a handler for `onTouchTap`. However, the only way I can see to redirect is by using the components `Redirect` or `Link`. How could I change the URL without rendering those two components?

I've tried `this.context.router.push('/foo')` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try this,

```
this.props.router.push('/foo')
```

***warning*** works for versions prior to v4

and

```
this.props.history.push('/foo')
```

for **v4 and above**

Comment: @Alex The method are now passed as props intead of through context. But I am still having multiple issue with this stuff in production

Comment: So this means I need to pass down to the child components the router object myself, right?

Comment: no, router will be there already, no need to pass

Comment: I believe you must have to pass the props. e.g. `<Route path="/one" render={() => <MyComponent />}/>`. If I try to access props inside `MyComponent`, I don't believe that `props.router` will exist. `props` isn't a global variable and you can't just inject stuff into it.

Comment: N.B. **This is for an old version of React Router** (current version is v4)

Comment: If you're using a HOC you'll want to `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom` and wrap your component with it (i.e. `export default withRouter(MyComponent)`). This gives you access to the `history` prop.

Comment: You can make use of the [`useHistory`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) thing.

Answer (score 43):

I'm using this to redirect with **React Router v4**:

```
this.props.history.push('/foo');
```

Comment: N.B. The subtle change from `router` to `history`. This is what I've used in the end to for v4

Comment: @AbhirajshriWinsome mine wasn't edited too many times since I answered. Mine has have `history` since always, Ayush Sharma answer did not.

Answer (score 7):

> **React Router v4**

There's a couple of things that I needed to get this working smoothly.

The doc page on [auth workflow](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) has quite a lot of what is required.

However I had three issues

1. Where does the `props.history` come from?
2. How do I pass it through to my component which isn't directly inside the `Route` component
3. What if I want other `props`?

I ended up using:

1. option 2 from [an answer on 'Programmatically navigate using react router'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121109/327074) - i.e. to use [`<Route render>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) which gets you `props.history` which can then be passed down to the children.
2. Use the `render={routeProps => <MyComponent {...props} {routeProps} />}` to combine other `props` from [this answer on 'react-router - pass props to handler component'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43299633/327074)

N.B. With the `render` method you have to pass through the props from the `Route` component explicitly. You also want to use `render` and not `component` for performance reasons (`component` forces a reload every time).

```
const App = (props) => (
    <Route 
        path="/home" 
        render={routeProps => <MyComponent {...props} {...routeProps}>}
    />
)

const MyComponent = (props) => (
    /**
     * @link https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow
     * N.B. I use `props.history` instead of `history`
     */
    <button onClick={() => {
        fakeAuth.signout(() => props.history.push('/foo'))
    }}>Sign out</button>
)
```

One of the confusing things I found is that in quite a few of the React Router v4 docs they use `MyComponent = ({ match })` i.e. [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), which meant initially I didn't realise that `Route` passes down three props, `match`, `location` and `history`

I think some of the other answers here are assuming that everything is done via JavaScript classes.

Here's an example, plus if you don't need to pass any `props` through you can just use `component`

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        <Route 
            path="/home" 
            component={MyComponent}
        />
    }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render () {
        /**
         * @link https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow
         * N.B. I use `props.history` instead of `history`
         */
        <button onClick={() => {
            this.fakeAuth.signout(() => this.props.history.push('/foo'))
        }}>Sign out</button>
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to append to the current URL? Like if the current URL was `google.com/:search`, then I wanted to make it `google.com/:search/vendor`... or something.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did a similar thing. I have tiles that are thumbnails to YouTube videos. When I click the tile, it redirects me to a 'player' page that uses the 'video_id' to render the correct video to the page.

```
<GridTile
  key={video_id}
  title={video_title}
  containerElement={<Link to={`/player/${video_id}`}/>}
 >
```

ETA: Sorry, just noticed that you didn't want to use the LINK or REDIRECT components for some reason. Maybe my answer will still help in some way. ; )