# Trying to make a sub page (channel) in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make the user able to create channels in my web app.

If you the see image below, there is a modal that take the input and use

that as the id of the page that will newly created.

[image]

My route is specified as:

```
require('./styles/main.scss');

render(

    <Router> 
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/RecTest" component={RecTest}/>
            <Route exact path="/Example" component={Example}/>
            <Route path="/channels/:id" component={ (props) => (<Channel {...props}/>)} />
        </div>
    </Router>,

    // Define your router and replace <Home /> with it!
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And the modal is coded as:

```
class MakeChannelModal extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log("constructor");
        this.state={
            channelName: ''
        }

        this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
        this.inputChangeHandler = this.inputChangeHandler.bind(this);
    }

    inputChangeHandler(event) {

        this.setState({
            channelName: event.target.value
        })
    }

    clickHandler() {
        <Link to={{ pathname: '/channels/' + this.state.channelName }}></Link> 
    }


    render(){
        return(

            <div className="ui active modal">
                <div className="header">Create a New Channel</div>
                <div className="loginbody">
                    <div className="fillout">
                        <div className="channelName">
                            <span>Channel Name: </span>                            
                            <Input
                                onChange = { this.inputChangeHandler }
                                placeholder="Channel Name"
                                label = "Channel Name"
                                value = { this.state.channelName } />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Button onClick = { this.clickHandler }>
                        SUBMIT
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
     )
    }
}

export default MakeChannelModal
```

I was assuming this to take the channel name input and direct the page to a `Channel` component with the id of `df`.

My Channel component is just blank right now.

The thing is, if I click SUBMIT in the modal, it does not do anything.

Doesn't even show an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clickHandler()` should be a function that changes pathname, making `Router` to draw another component, but it tries to draw React component by itself instead (not quite successfully though, because this function doesn't actually returns anything).

I believe you should either use `props.history.push()` in `onClick()`, or make `<Button />` a `<Link />`.

**Solution 1:** (preferable, if you want a `<Button>`)

Replace your `clickHandler()` with this:

```
clickHandler() {
  this.props.history.push('/channels/' + this.state.channelName);
}
```

**Solution 2:** (still would work)

Replace your `<Button ... />` component with this:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/channels/' + this.state.channelName }}>
  SUBMIT
</Link>
```

SO answer about `history.push()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43298961/6376451

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does take me to the /channels/id link, but nothing appears in my new page even though I added stuffs in my Channel component.

Comment: Debugging will probably require more code, specifically Channel component. While testing I just did a dummy and it worked.