# Pass props to handler component (that is defined in a variable)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Similar to [react-router - pass props to handler component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component) but in my case my component was declared in a variable in my case `elem.component` and I am trying to build an array of routes passing a `showModal` function.

This is what I had tried so far

```
routes.push(
  <Route key={elem.to} exact path={elem.to}
     component={elem.component} showModal={this.props.showModal}/>)
```

I was looking at the render methods for the other answers but they have the component defined in the function which I do not have in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass component using function binding

`<Route exact path="/" component={() => (<Component prop={val} />) }/>`

Comment: My component is `elem.component` a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign component to a capitalized variable to use it in JSX - please check this React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) for more details about defining element type at runtime. Please try this:

```
<Route key={elem.to} exact path={elem.to}
     render={() => {
        const MyComponent = elem.component;
        return <MyComponent showModal={someValue} />
     }}

/>
```