# Setup react route to use URL parameters and props' function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've got a parent component with react-router, setup like this :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        diner: false
    };

    this.updateFromInvite = this.updateFromInvite.bind(this);
}

updateFromInvite(Souper) {
    this.setState({diner: Souper});
}
```

I can't figure out how to setup the **route to have both URL parameters and be able to pass a function** to update the parent's state from the children component...

```
<Route path="/Invitation/:NomParam1?/:NomParam2?" 
       component = {() => (<Invitation updateApp = {this.updateFromInvite} />)} />
```

I think it's the closest I got...

From children's component :

```
class Invite extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            diner: this.props.match.params.NomParam1 ,
            JSONInfo: this.props.match.params.NomParam2
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { diner } = this.state;
        const { JSONInfo } = this.state;
        const { updateApp } = this.props;
        updateApp(diner);
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Invite">
        <div className="col-centered">
            <VidPlay/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Invite;
```

Comment: You seem to mix up `render` with `component`. The render method has a parameter that contains the `match` that made the route active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `component` property of the route takes a component `Class`, not an instance of the component.  I believe you are looking to use the `render` property, which takes a rendered component.  Your visual component shouldn't be concerned with the routing details, so you can pass that in in the `Route` configuration like so:

```
<Route path="/Invitation/:NomParam1?/:NomParam2?" 
  render={({match}) => (
    <Invitation
      updateApp={this.updateFromInvite}
      diner={match.params.NomParam1}
      JSONInfo={match.params.NomParam2}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Then, in the component, don't utilize `state`, as that's not really what it is for:

```
class Invite extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { diner, JSONInfo, updateApp } = this.props;

        // Not exactly sure what is going on here... how you
        // will use JSONInfo, etc
        updateApp(diner);
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Invite">
        <div className="col-centered">
            <VidPlay/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, I'm not *exactly* sure what the parent component is doing, and why it is passing both the route params and the function down to the child, only to have the child call it back... but that is probably out of the scope of the question.

Enjoy!

Comment: I'm still getting `Cannot read property 'params' of undefined` on `diner: this.props.match.params.NomParam1` . Even, when I'm trying with parameters... If I take a closer look at `this.props` inside children, I do have `updateApp`, but I no longer have `match`, `location`, `history`, ...

Comment: Oh, I see... yeah, that's because I didn't see that you are reading the match parameters in your component.  Your component shouldn't be concerned with routing... it should take two parameters (not state).  From what I understand of your example, it would be `diner` and `JSONInfo`, though I don't know what `JSONInfo` is... it probably needs a different name.

I'll update the example.

Answer (score 0):

If finally got it (thanks to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43299633/4628637) and [the official documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)):

I needed to add `props` as parameter of my render and
use it with `{...props}` inside the children element!

```
<Route path="/Invitation/:NomParam1?/:NomParam2?" 
       render={ (props) => 
                (<Invitation updateApp = {this.updateFromInvite} {...props} />) 
              }
/>
```

With that, I have access to BOTH :

- my custom props
- generic props (`match`, `location` and `history`)