# if function is not up to date react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in this amazing site, I'm just having a problem in my react app.

this is the `index.js` I'm using `react-router-dom` in this page I just need to show `this.state.show` for who is in a home page, So in the `login.js request` I've created `'loginToken'` with this code `sessionStorage.setItem('loginToken', 'Value')`

and now I'm making a verification for `sessionStorage.getItem('loginToken')` in index.js

**Everything works fine but my problem is when I'm in a home page** this text `'Welcome Back'` doesn't appears automatically I need to refresh the home page to see it. I don't know why this happening.

Is it because I'm using componentWillMount?

I've tried to use `componentDidMount` I got same problem

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './users/login';
import home from './news/index';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        if(sessionStorage.getItem('loginToken')){
            this.setState({show: true});
        }else{
            this.setState({show: false});
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.show?
                <div>welcome back</div>:null
                }
            <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/home" component={home} />
                    </Switch>
            </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: does this only happen after you login for the first time?

Comment: Yes it is, I need to refresh to see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is `componentWillMount` only fires once when the app first is run since it is the most top level component in the tree.

You should look to pass a function as a prop into the Login component and call it in the login component to trigger a state change back in the parent component. You could follow an approach to doing so in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component).

The easiest approach would be to just move that welcome back text into a dashboard or home route this way it mounts and unmounts as you are expecting and you can use your current approach in that component.

Comment: Thank you so much Eric for your answer.