# React router pass props to route component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass props from my app.jsx to one of my route components using react router but I get the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'acc' of undefined

Here's the code from my app.jsx:

```
<Route exact path='/FileUpload' acc={this.state.account} ethAdd={this.state.ethAddress} component={FileUpload} />
```

And the code in the component that route leads to:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.setState({
            account: this.props.route.acc,
            ethAddress: this.props.route.ethAdd
        })
    }
```

I don't really understand from reading other solutions on here how this passing of props in react router works, can anyone help me understand what I need to do?

Comment: Consider redux or some other state management. Pretty sure I can guess what you're doing and it's going to get  really complex really quick! If not, the answer below is how you pass custom stuff to routes

Comment: The answer below is correct... The only thing I would add is the constructor is where you initialize your state `this.state = {...}` not `setState`...

Comment: Have 15 days left of this project so perhaps a bit too late to learn redux... what I'm trying to do is have my app.jsx always maintain the users Metamask account so I can then pass it to that page. I know this might not be the best way to do this but I was having great issues trying to get this to work in that component

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<Route>` does not pass custom props to components. Use [render function](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) instead:

```
<Route exact path='/FileUpload' render={
  (props) => <FileUpload {...props} acc={this.state.account} ethAdd={this.state.ethAddress} />
} />
```

As SakoBu mentioned you need to change your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        account: this.props.acc,
        ethAddress: this.props.ethAdd
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So that passes the variables I need to my component, but how do I then access them in that component?

Comment: As usual: `this.props.acc`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something again but that returns this error: >  Line 12:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

  10 |         this.state = {
  11 |             account = this.props.acc,
> 12 |             ethAddress: this.props.ethAdd,
     |                             ^
  13 | 
  14 |             user: '',
  15 |             uid: '',

Comment: Well, I'm a big dumb-dumb, I had a "=" instead of ':', thank you for your help everyone!

Comment: How would you access the props that this component is getting on a higher component matched as well?

Answer (score 15):

Here are few ways you can pass props to a route component.

With the react-router v5, we can create routes by wrapping with a `<Route>` component, so that we can easily pass props to the desired component like this.

```js
<Route path="/">
    <Home name="Sai" />
</Route>
```

Similarly, you can use the children prop in v5.

```js
<Route path="/" children={ <Home name="Sai" />} />
```

If you are using react-router v4, you can pass it using the render prop.

```js
<Route path="/" render={() => <Home name="Sai" />} />
```

(originally posted at https://reactgo.com/react-router-pass-props/)