# How to pass props to route in react router v5 with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a route that looks like this, which renders just fine:

```
<Route
  exact={true} 
  path="/"
  render={() => {
    return <Home />
  }}
/>
```

If I add in any prop

```
<Route
  exact={true}
  path="/"
  render={() => {
    return <Home foo="bar" />
  }}
/>
```

I get the following warning:

> Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes
> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'foo' does not exist on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2322

How can I pass props to a component with Typescript?

My `Home` component looks like this:

```
type homeType = {
  foo: string
}

const Home: React.FC = ({ foo }: homeType) => { 
  return <p>{foo}</p>
}
```

Comment: Looks like this has nothing to do with React Router, can you post your `Home` component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router - pass props to handler component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component)

Comment: Thanks, but no it does not. i can't even pass a static string like `foo` in my example.

Comment: It seems like this is what I need, but it's far far too difficult for me to understand: https://medium.com/@robjtede/the-real-routewithprops-react-component-in-typescript-defacde01991

Answer (score 2):

Your home component needs to be defined with the props which will be sent to it, i.e.

```js
import React from 'react';

type CardProps = {
  title: string,
  paragraph: string
}

export const Card = ({ title, paragraph }: CardProps) => 
<aside>
  <h2>{ title }</h2>
  <p>
    { paragraph }
  </p>
</aside>

const el = <Card title="Welcome!" paragraph="To this example" />
```

So with your example i presume you have a component called Home, which should be defined as such

```js
type HomeProps = {
  foo: string
}

export const Home= ({ foo }: HomeProps) => 
  <h2>{ foo }</h2>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. i unfortunately can't seem to get it to work. can you use my example?

Comment: @turtle i have updated my answer to reflect your code above