# How to get data from url in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example i redirected in my spa on localhost:3000/ProductPage/014
How can i take '014' value to my react variable?

```
      <Route exact
        path="/ProductPage/:id"
        render={() => <ProductPage data={data} />}
      />
```

Comment: [`useParams()`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router - pass props to handler component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864720/react-router-pass-props-to-handler-component)

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are using react-router-dom, You can use `useParams()`.

```
import {
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
```

then in your component ->

```
let { id } = useParams();
```

For more detailed example you can see [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

Comment: I just take it using it: window.location.href

Comment: that works, but if you have a more complicated route, like `users/:user_id/posts/post_id`, it would be more difficult to extract the values